# Azure container app set environment variables

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-container-apps

I am trying to set the environment variables of container in azure container app but getting issue when there is space on the value.
my .env is as below

```
BD_PASSWORD=v=K1i2
WS_PROJECT_AR_DSO=https://example.com
AUTO_BATCH_SUBMIT_CRON_START_TIME=*/2 * * * *
EMAIL_WHITELIST=["a.com","b.net"]
```

I tried with key=value space-separated, but it failed
I tried "key1=value" "key2=value2" , but it again failed

How to send space separated and/or value with contains double quotes like Email whitelist value.
I am using Azure CLI with the following command

```
  az containerapp update \
  --name ca-devpi \
  --resource-group rg-dev-pi \
  --image ${{ secrets.ACR_SERVER }}/dev-pi:latest  \
  --container-name dev-pi \
  --cpu 1.0 --memory 2Gi \
  --min-replicas 0 --max-replicas 2 \
  --scale-rule-name my-http-rule \
  --scale-rule-type http \
  --scale-rule-http-concurrency 15 \
  --set-env-vars $SPACE_SEPARATED_VALUES
```

And the error I am getting

```
 ERROR: Environment variables must be in the format "<key>=<value> <key>=secretref:<value> ...".
```

**Update**

After trying the suggestion from @Azeem and @SiddheshDesai. I can see similar behavior. i.e. if I print $SPACE_SEPARATED_VALUES I can see values are in the format of `"AUTO_BATCH_SUBMIT_CRON_START_TIME=*/2 * * * *" "EMAIL_WHITELIST=[\"a.com\",\"b.net\"]"`

but I pass the same variable as `--set-env-vars $SPACE_SEPARATED_VALUES`
then I am getting the same error that

```
ERROR: Environment variables must be in the format "<key>=<value> <key>=secretref:<value> ...
```

If i pass with double quotes like this

```
--set-env-vars "$SPACE_SEPARATED_VALUES"
```

then I am getting error

```
ERROR: (ContainerAppInvalidEnvVarName) Env variable name '"AUTO_BATCH_SUBMIT_CRON_START_TIME' contains invalid character, regex used for validation is '^[-._a-zA-Z][-._a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
```

And I pass direct values like this

```
--set-env-vars "AUTO_BATCH_SUBMIT_CRON_START_TIME=*/2 * * * *" "EMAIL_WHITELIST=[\"a.com\",\"b.net\"]"
```

then it works. Now this my be because of Azure CLI shell because this is how I am using

```
- name: Update Container app
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            az containerapp update \
            --name ${{ vars.DBA_APP }} \
            --resource-group ${{ vars.CONTAINER_RG }} \
            --set-env-vars $SPACE_SEPARATED_VALUES
```

Comment: Use double quote as suggested in the error message i.e. `--set-env-vars "k1=v1 k2=v2 ..."`. Given that you have different types of values that have nested quotes, you have to escape those. You can use https://www.shellcheck.net/ with the actual expanded values to fix quotes' issues.

Comment: @Mahajan az containerapp update \
  --name my-xxxxx \
  --resource-group xxxxxurces \
  --image my-container-app  \
  --container-name my-container-app \
  --cpu 1.0 --memory 2Gi \
  --min-replicas 0 --max-replicas 2 \
  --scale-rule-name my-http-rule \
  --scale-rule-type http \
  --scale-rule-http-concurrency 15 \
  --set-env-vars "BD_PASSWORD=v=K1i2" "WS_PROJECT_AR_DSO=https://example.com" "AUTO_BATCH_SUBMIT_CRON_START_TIME=*/2 * * * *" "EMAIL_WHITELIST=[\"a.com\",\"b.net\"]" \
  This commands works on my end, Try adding the variables inside the quote like this command?

Comment: @Azeem I have updated my question, please see the update

Comment: @Mahajan344: Seems like you have to do some intermediate processing to set those values properly i.e. format env vars accordingly as the one in your last command that works. Also, please include your relevant GHA workflow in your question showing how you're using all these together.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below ***`Azure CLI`*** command and put the **`env vars`** in double quotes like below:-

**My Github Action workflow:-**

Complete workflow **[here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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)**

```yaml
on: [push]

name: AzureLoginSample

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: Upload to blob storage
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            az containerapp update \
              --name valleycontainerapp95 \
              --resource-group siliconrg98 \
              --image mcr.microsoft.com/k8se/quickstart:latest \
              --container-name simple-hello-world-container \
              --cpu 1.0 --memory 2Gi \
              --min-replicas 0 --max-replicas 2 \
              --scale-rule-name my-http-rule \
              --scale-rule-type http \
              --scale-rule-http-concurrency 15 \
              --set-env-vars "BD_PASSWORD=v=K1i2 WS_PROJECT_AR_DSO=example.com" "AUTO_BATCH_SUBMIT_CRON_START_TIME=*/2 * * * *" "EMAIL_WHITELIST=[\"a.com\",\"b.net\"]"
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question, please see the update

Comment: In your env file itself try to add double quotes to your variables like here and run your command -  "BD_PASSWORD=v=K1i2"
"WS_PROJECT_AR_DSO=https://example.com"
"AUTO_BATCH_SUBMIT_CRON_START_TIME=*/2 * * * *"
"EMAIL_WHITELIST=["a.com","b.net"]"

Comment: Please see the "Update" on the original question... issue is with shell.. vairables are in same format

Answer (score 0):

If anyone came here looking for how to add multiple environment variables dynamically by using a variable here's a solution I found running `az containerapp` command in bash:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# I usually run some commands to parse a json into a key=value space separated string
env_vars='"key1=val1" "key2=val2" "key3=val3"' 
create_revision_cmd="az containerapp update \
  -n $CONTAINERAPP \
  -g $RESOURCE_GROUP \
  --image "$IMAGE" \
  --replace-env-vars $env_vars" # or --set-env-vars

cmd_output=$(eval $create_revision_cmd)
```